# Using HTMX, hx-push-url

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, htmx

just looking for some detailed pointers on how to `hx-push-url` as I have come across some problems and looking for some direction. I am a relative beginner at Django and just started using HTMX.

The aim. I'm building a simple image gallery and have a grid of thumbnails, I am using HTMX to load the list of images within that gallery when a uses click a thumbnail.

This works well, I am using Django-HTMX and a `if` conditional in the `View` to deal with the HTMX request which serves the partial HTML into the thumbnail page.

The problem was that my URL did not change. My thumbnail is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/` and when I click on a gallery to view images within, the url remains the same, so, I used htmx-push-url so that URL would appear something like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/news`. This works and the URL changes.

Anyway, onward.

I have a button on my images list page that take you back to the thumbnail page, but when using this I get a `404` error, and also when I refresh my image list page I get a `404`. Obviously there is no URL and view for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/news`. I Just have little idea how to solve this.

When I look in the console I get a `HTMX-target error` when clicked the back button, and nothing happens. And, as I say, a refresh gets a 404.

Code below should explain things better.

Models

```
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,
                                   help_text="Gallery description on gallery page")
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    visable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey('Media', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    album_images = models.ManyToManyField('Media', related_name="album_pictures")

    class Media(models.Model):

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    visable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

URLS (relevant)

```
path("gallery/", views.GalleryView, name="gallery"),
```

Views

```
def GalleryView(request):

    if request.htmx:
        slug = request.GET.get('slug')
        pics = get_object_or_404(Albums, slug=slug)
        context = {'pictures': Media.objects.filter(album_pictures=pics),
                   'description': Albums.objects.filter(slug=slug)}
        return render(request, 'main/gallery-detail.html', context=context)

    context = {'objects_list': Albums.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'main/gallery.html', context=context)
```

Gallery HTML {relevant code)

```
<div class="gallery-body">
{% for img in objects_list %}
    <div class="item col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <figure class="overlay"> <a hx-post="{{ request.path }}?slug={{ img.slug }}"
                                    hx-target=".gallery-body"
                                    hx-swap="outerHTML"
                                    hx-push-url="/gallery/{{ img.slug }}"
                    hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
          {% endfor %}
```

The partial that gets called showing the images within the galleries.

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary"
                  hx-get="{% url 'main:gallery' %}"
                  hx-target=".gallery-body"
                  hx-push-url="/gallery"
                  hx-headers='{"X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
                  <h6>Back to Gallery page</h6></button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `hx-replace-url = "true" hx-push-url = "true"`. I think that will pick up the url from your `hx-get` statement.